# It won't let me scroll

Tags: html, css

The code is below and it won't let me scroll.
[https://codepen.io/duggalverse/project/full/DkoeNr][1]
swdefrgtyhujiuhygtfrgthghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

I also want to fix the transparency part so it only gets the text part-any help would be great!!

Last thing I need help in is the background image....it keeps getting repeated no matter what I try...

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/duggalverse/project/full/DkoeNr
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>About Me</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        
        body{
            background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/S7jLZD8/IMG-20190904-WA0000.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-position-y: center; /*add*/
            font-family: tahoma;
            overflow: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }
        .main-banner {
            position: relative;
            padding: 50px;
            max-width: 800px;
            /*max-width: 25%;*/ /*add*/
            height: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: top center;
            background-size: cover;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255,.2);

            box-shadow: 0 50px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
            
            /*margin: 0 55% 0 auto;*/ /*add*/
            
            margin: 10% auto;   /*add*/
            margin-right: 55%;


        }
        
        
        /*add class*/
        .col-md-6 {
           width: 100%;
         }
        
        .main-banner .text p{
            color: white;
        }
        p, .text{
            position: relative;
            line-height: 1.8em;
            font-family: tahoma;
            text-align: justify;

        }
        .sec-title.light .title, .sec-title.light h2{
            color: white;
        }

        .btn-style-one{
            position: relative;
            line-height: 30px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: 700;
            border: 1px solid #fdb30e;
            background: #fdb40e;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            padding: 15px 50px 15px;

        }



        
    </style>
</head>x    
<body>
    <section class="main-banner container">

        <div class="auto-con">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <div class="sec-title light col-md-6">
                    <div class="title">Hello</div>
                    <h2>ABOUT ME: <br>

                        <span style="font-size: 60px;">DUGGALverse</span>
                    </h2>

                    <br><br>

                    <div class="text">
                        <p>
                            I'm a self-taught coder utilizing the internet tools to teach myself. With proven communication and creative thinking skills I am always attempting to best myself. I am an aficionado in various innovation fields and plan to keep investigating different dialects in Computer Science. Meaning to use my capacities to effectively fill in the job in your organization/association. Much of the time applauded as persistent by my associates, I can be depended upon to support your organization/association to accomplish its objectives. 
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            As a profoundly gifted studen with involvement in the community, I have an assortment of aptitudes and information that would be of incredible advantage to your company. This activity posting is an incredible open door for me to keep expanding on my  experience while picking up introduction to a huge frameworks driven plan of action. I  like to use my dynamic data innovation range of abilities alongside my group driven character to propel information handling within the role I have currently applied for. I accept that my appended resume will show that I am a brilliant contender for this position. My solid initiative capacities has permitted me to effectively combine and solidify numerous ventures as a candidate within the role I amjapplying for, and I am certain they will permit me to keep on settling on trustworthy choices as an ideal candidate. I approach my work with a hands-on perspective, taking on jobs all through the lifetime of an undertaking. I additionally have a solid scholarly foundation in the coding genre seen clearly.

                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <div class="btn-box">
                        <a href="" class="theme-btn btn-style-one">Download My Resume</a>
                        
                        <br><br><br>
                        <div class="image">
                            <img src="">
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


     </section>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the body is having `overflow: hidden`. Remove that and you should be able to scroll.

Secondly, you put the `background-repeat` on the `.main-banner`, when it should be on the body where you set the `background-image`. Also, your `background-size` doesn't have a '-' in the middle.